# Distinguishing a pipe from a file in Unix

Tags: c, unix, file, pipe, manpage

Given a FILE*, is it possible to determine the underlying type?  That is, is there a function that will tell me if the FILE* is a pipe or a socket or a regular on-disk file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a `fstat(2)` function.

NAME
       stat, fstat, lstat - get file status

SYNOPSIS

```
   #include <sys/types.h>
   #include <sys/stat.h>
   #include <unistd.h>

   int fstat(int fd, struct stat *buf);
```

You can get the fd by calling `fileno(3)`.

Then you can call `S_ISFIFO(buf)` to figure it out.

Comment: might have been worth mentioning: `S_ISFIFO(buf.st_mode)` this macro doesn't crawl the structure for you.

Answer (score 3):

Use the fstat() function.  However, you'll need to use the fileno() macro to get the file descriptor from file FILE struct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

FILE *fp = fopen(path, "r");
int fd = fileno(fp);
struct stat statbuf;

fstat(fd, &statbuf);

/* a decoding case statement would be good here */
printf("%s is file type %08o\n", path, (statbuf.st_mode & 0777000);
```

Comment: This is a good example but to an inexperienced coder it doesn't make sense. Q&A should always be generalized to the base problem so that others who have similar problems can understand the answer in similar contexts. The question was distinguishing a pipe from a file in unix. Your answer just shows how to parse a stat mode. It is a great example you just did not answer the question properly. The answer to this question is `FILE *fp = fopen(path, "r");
int fd = fileno(fp); 
struct stat statbuf; 
fstat(fd, &statbuf); if (S_ISFIFO(statbuf.st_mode)) //its a pipe!`